# Apache how to redirect to other port?

Tags: html, apache, redirect

On a rpi with Apache i want to redirect port 80 to port 6830.
index.html;

```
    <! -- Redirect to port  -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 15 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=:6830">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Heading1" style="position:absolute;left:46px;top:19px;width:522px;height:69px;z-index:0;">
<h1 id="Heading1">Untitled Page</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives http://192.168.178.99/:6830

How can I remove / from the link

Comment: Trying giving the exact URL instead of just port.

Comment: What is the OS you are using?

Comment: I can not give the exact url, the rpi gets a url depending on the network

Comment: It will redirect all pages on port 80 to port 6830

Answer (score 2):

You can use rewrite rules to redirect them, make sure [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is enabled in your apache, add it to .htaccess or httpd.conf :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:6830%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you only want to redirect index.php, use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:6830%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Let me know if it doesn't work :)